# WPF RichTextBox CaretPosition

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, richtextbox

I am trying to program a WordPad (not Notepad) in WPF.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fontSizeComBox.ItemsSource = new List<double>() { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 36, 48, 72 };
}

private void fontSizeComBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Run r = new Run();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    r.FontSize = (double)fontSizeComBox.SelectedValue;
    richTextBox.CaretPosition.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(r);
    richTextBox.CaretPosition = r.ElementStart;
    richTextBox.Focus();
}
```

I ran into a problem while using it.

1. Write a text
2. Place caret in the middle of text
3. Change text size
4. The cursor jumps to the end of the run

Comment: have you tried swapping the focus and the caret position lines ?

Comment: yes, but nothing changed